# XTS Apply Family and a Multi Column XTS?

Tags: r, xts

How do I use the apply family of functions, say `apply.daily` to a multivariate XTS?

So for example:

```
Time,a,b
...
2012-02-11 16:21:24 4.7258 7.7258
2012-02-11 16:26:25 4.9096 12.3796
2012-02-11 16:31:25 4.7904 2.2204
...
```

How would I use `apply.daily` and `mean` to the entire matrix by column. So the result would be a single time stamp for the day, the mean of `a` for the next column, and the mean of `b` for the column after that.

I would like to do this for arbitrary number columns (the amount of columns and names are not known -- all numeric of course).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could simply use `colMeans` to take the mean of every column:

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY")
spy1 <- apply.weekly(SPY, colMeans)
```

You could also define an arbitrary function that uses `apply` over the columns of your object:

```
spy2 <- apply.weekly(SPY, function(x) apply(x,2,mean))
identical(spy1,spy2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: My database is in months and has multi-columns, how can I group by, for example, 10 years and apply the mean.