# Sum of values within a week

Tags: r, time-series, xts, zoo

I want to sum the values in each column of a frame by week. I can do the mean, but the sum doesn't work for some reason:

```
> zoo.data <- zoo(data.frame(x=11:20,y=1:10),as.Date(1:10,origin="1970-01-01"))
> apply.weekly(zoo.data, mean)
            x y
1970-01-04 12 2
1970-01-11 17 7
> apply.weekly(zoo.data, sum)
1970-01-04 1970-01-11 
        42        168
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a result of the fact that the **xts** authors have decided to add a `mean.xts` method to mimic the old behavior of base R (and which is essentially `colMeans`).  `mean.xts` is now dispatched on `xts` objects instead of `mean.default`, and `apply.weekly` temporarily converts your `zoo` object to an `xts` internally.

```
R> apply.weekly(zoo.data, mean)
            x y
1970-01-04 12 2
1970-01-11 17 7
R> apply.weekly(zoo.data, mean.default)
1970-01-04 1970-01-11 
         7         12
```

---

But, I think this is what you want to do:

```
R> apply.weekly(zoo.data, colMeans)
            x y
1970-01-04 12 2
1970-01-11 17 7
R> apply.weekly(zoo.data, colSums)
             x  y
1970-01-04  36  6
1970-01-11 119 49
```

Comment: +1, but note this is only currently true for xts on R-Forge. `mean.xts` is not registered in *xts_0.8-8* on CRAN.

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich what about `apply.weekly(zoo.data, var)` or `apply.weekly(zoo.data, sd)`?  Been searching around why they don't work like `mean`

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich got it https://stackoverflow.com/a/9242189/5823517.  Great package by the way.